# jQuery 2.1 | Remove duplicate li from top to bottom of list

Tags: jquery, duplicates, html-lists

This code removes duplicate li from bottom to top in an unordered list. How can it be modified to remove duplicate li from top to bottom?

```
function removeDuplicates(){
  var map = {};
  $("UL").find(".data").each(function() {
    var value = $(this);
    if (map[value.text()] == null){
      map[value.text()] = true;
    } else {
      $(this).parent('li').remove();
    }
  });
}
```

If nothing can be done with the above sample, any other type of efficient code sample answering the question will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to store the current element and then remove the previous element like

```
function removeDuplicates() {
    var map = {};
    $("UL").find(".data").each(function () {
        var value = $(this);
        if (map[value.text()]) {
            map[value.text()].parent('li').remove();
        }
        map[value.text()] = value;
    });
}
```

Demo:

```js
function removeDuplicates() {
  var map = {};
  $("UL").find(".data").each(function() {
    var value = $(this);
    if (map[value.text()]) {
      map[value.text()].parent('li').remove();
    }
    map[value.text()] = value;
  });
}

removeDuplicates();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span class="data">1</span></li>
  <li><span class="data">2</span></li>
  <li><span class="data">3</span></li>
  <li><span class="data">2</span></li>
  <li><span class="data">1</span></li>
  <li><span class="data">4</span></li>
  <li><span class="data">5</span></li>
  <li><span class="data">2</span></li>
</ul>
```